# Spring-kafka-test testing JSON message with custom deserialization

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, spring-kafka-test

I've mostly successfully set up a test using EmbeddedKafka, which produces and consumes one message. Below is a working version of the test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@EmbeddedKafka
public class KafkaFlowTest {

    @Autowired
    EmbeddedKafkaBroker broker;

    public static final String EMAIL_TOPIC = "email-service";

    static {
        System.setProperty(EmbeddedKafkaBroker.BROKER_LIST_PROPERTY, "spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers");
    }

    private Consumer<String, KafkaEmailMessageWrapper> consumer;
    private Producer<String, KafkaEmailMessageWrapper> producer;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        Map<String, Object> consumerProps = KafkaTestUtils.consumerProps("group", "true", broker);
        consumerProps.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        consumerProps.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonDeserializer.class);
        consumerProps.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
        consumerProps.put(JsonDeserializer.TRUSTED_PACKAGES, "*");
        Map<String, Object> producerProps = KafkaTestUtils.producerProps(broker);
        producerProps.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        producerProps.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class);

        DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<String, KafkaEmailMessageWrapper> cf =
                new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(
                        consumerProps,
                        new StringDeserializer(),
                        new JsonDeserializer<>(KafkaEmailMessageWrapper.class)
                );
        consumer = cf.createConsumer();
        consumer.subscribe(Collections.singleton(EMAIL_TOPIC));
        consumer.poll(Duration.ZERO);

        DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<String, KafkaEmailMessageWrapper> pf =
                new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(producerProps);
        producer = pf.createProducer();
    }

    @Test
    public void testNoErrorMessageFlow() {
        KafkaEmailMessageWrapper wrapperMessage = KafkaEmailMessageWrapper.builder()
                .emailRequest(
                    EmailMessage.builder()
                        .body("body")
                        .from("me@me.com")
                        .to(new String[]{"you@you.com"})
                        .subject("hey!")
                        .build()
                )
                .build();

        producer.send(new ProducerRecord<>(EMAIL_TOPIC, "whatever", wrapperMessage));
        producer.flush();

        ConsumerRecord<String, KafkaEmailMessageWrapper> record = KafkaTestUtils.getSingleRecord(consumer, EMAIL_TOPIC);
        KafkaEmailMessageWrapper receivedMessage = record.value();
        assertEquals(wrapperMessage.getEmailRequest().getSubject(), receivedMessage.getEmailRequest().getSubject());
    }

}
```

This works fine, unless I add assertEquals on the `to` field, which in JSON comes as a list of email addresses separated by `;` and in the class is an array of Strings. So in the `EmailMessage` class I have the `to` field annotated with `@JsonDeserializer` pointing to a custom deserializer that splits along `;`, etc. Everything works when the app is run, only tests break.

I tried to modify the code above to change the `Producer<String, KafkaEmailMessageWrapper> producer` to `private Producer<String, String> producer` and then in the test send JSON instead of the `KafkaEmailMessageWrapper` instance, but then I get an exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.test.model.KafkaEmailMessageWrapper
```

So it looks like the deserialization from JSON string to the model is for some reason not happening in this test scenario. I would like the test be as close to real use case as possible, so it should produce a string message and then perform deserialization to my model class. Not sure why this is not happening, any help in understanding why that is would be appreciated!

For completion, this is the definition of message listener:

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "email-service")
public void receive(@Payload KafkaEmailMessageWrapper message)
```

**EDIT**

Let me rephrase the problem, because maybe I confused things a bit.
Overview of the app is:

- consume a JSON message
- serialize it into `KafkaEmailMessageWrapper`
- send an email

This works, I send a JSON to Kafka, it's received (listener definition above) and proceeds correctly. The only problem I have is while testing.

I want to mimic the same situation in the test, but when I do this:

`kafkaTemplate.sendDefault("key", "<json message>");`

I get a:

```
Cannot handle message; nested exception is  org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: Cannot convert from [java.lang.String] to [com.test.model.KafkaEmailMessageWrapper] for GenericMessage
```

However when I send a `KafkaEmailMessageWrapper` instance instead:

`kafkaTemplate.sendDefault("key", kafkaEmailMessageWrapper);`

it works, but then it doesn't use my `@JsonDeserialize` annotations I have specified on the class:

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = SemicolonArrayDeserializer.class)
private String[] to;
@JsonDeserialize(using = SemicolonArrayDeserializer.class)
private String[] cc;
```

So when sending an instance, to and cc fields are always empty, because in the fields already are arrays of strings, so the deserialize logic of splitting along `;` is not doing anything. This is the deserialize method:

```
public String[] deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = (ObjectMapper) p.getCodec();
    JsonNode node = mapper.readTree(p);
    return node.asText().split(";");
}
```

Comment: It's just getting `String subject` which represents the email's subject, I guess it's not really relevant here

Comment: Sorry, I meant describe exactly what this means `unless I add assertEquals on the to field` - what do you get?

Comment: @GaryRussell sorry, it's difficult to explain without writing an essay. I added the edit to the question, I hope now it makes more sense

Answer (score 0):

You need to show the stack trace, but I am guessing that because you are using `@SpringBootTest`, the real consumer (listener method) is also getting the message, which is why you are getting the exception.

It's not clear what you are testing here (with your test `Consumer`) object.

A better test would be to, say, have a `MailSender` service injected into your listener bean and in the test case inject a mock `MailSender` to verify it all worked as expected.